# node.js async waterfall more than one callback per function

Tags: node.js, async.js

May one call the callback function more than once when using async.waterfall? If so, why not?

I expected (apparently wrongly in the example below), one should be able to call the callback multiple times within a function.

Example:

```
var async = require("async");
var accumulator = [];
var moment = require("moment");

function results(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
}

function inserter(data, callback) {

    if (data === null) {
        callback(null, accumulator);
    } else {
        if (accumulator.length >= 5) {
            callback(null, accumulator);
            accumulator = [];
        } else {
            accumulator.push(data);
        }
    }
}

function iFindMultitudes(callback) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i = i + 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            callback(null, moment().format());
        }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) * 1000);
    }
    callback(null, null);
}

async.waterfall([
        iFindMultitudes,
        inserter
        ], results);
```

Which gives me:

```
[ '2014-06-18T11:49:17-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:17-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:18-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:19-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:20-04:00' ]
[ '2014-06-18T11:49:21-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:21-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:22-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:22-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:22-04:00' ]
[ '2014-06-18T11:49:23-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:23-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:23-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:23-04:00',
  '2014-06-18T11:49:25-04:00' ]
```

The function "iFindMultitudes" is, in my case, an xml parser function which returns multiple json objects which are handed off to an api. I am limited to n json objects per insert, and a given xml file will almost always exceed n.

What is weird to me here, is that the waterfall is apparently dying without throwing an error. The docs don't explicitly state that I cannot do it this way. (I know, I know.)

Am I trying to do something explicitly wrong here that is keeping my last values from being accumulated? If so, I'd love to know why.

UPDATE: Apparently this is a no-no

```
https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/559
https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/557
```

... but I'm still unclear on why it should be so.

Comment: Once you call the callback, it will always move onto the next function, unless of course you pass an error. In which case it will finish and go to the main callback.

Comment: If that is the case, how is my accumulator getting more than one value?